# How to create an msbuild "task" to nicely format output

Tags: msbuild

**Problem**

I have code like this in my msbuild files, all over the place:

```
<Message
    Text="$(NewLine)==============================================$(NewLine)"
    Importance="High" />
<Message
    Text="       CLEAN UP        "
    Importance="High" />
<Message
    Text="$(NewLine)==============================================$(NewLine)"
    Importance="High" />
```

**Goal**

now i would like to harmonize output and do reduce code redundancy and extract the message formatting logic to some kind of task or whatnot.

This is how i'm imagine the usage:

```
<Message Text="$(PrintInBox(CLEAN UP))" Importance="High"/>
```

so that i could also reuse it in

```
<Error Text="$(PrintInBox(CLEAN UP))"/>
```

If that is absolutely not possible, something like

```
<PrintInBox Text="CLEAN UP"/>
```

would be the next best thing.

---

**What i found so far**

The "best" thing i found so far is ["inline tasks"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd722601.aspx). 
but do i really need to write c# code to get the job done? It's just some simple string concatenation,...

Also using the custom task would be almost as cumbersome as duplicating the code all over, i guess it would look something like this:

```
<FormatInBox Text="CLEAN UP">
    <Output TaskParameter="Result" ItemName="FormattedText"/>
</FormatInBox>

<Message Text="@(FormattedText)" Importance="High"/>
```

or if i create more specific tasks:

```
<MessageInBox Text="CLEAN UP" Importance="High" />
```

and

```
<WarnInBox Text="CLEAN UP" Condition="..." />
```

and

```
<ErrorInBox Text="CLEAN UP" Condition = "..." />
```

but this will make it necessary to duplicate some of the parameters and pass them along. Also there's still code duplication across the `MessageInBox`, `WarnInBox` and `ErrorInBox` tasks.

**Question**

How can i achieve the simplest interface for the consumer? How can i reduce code-redundancy best?
Is there really no better way then the one i found before? Can i create an msbuild task which consist of msbuild xml, not C# or VB.net or Javascript or whatnot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Box>==============================================&#10;       Text&#10;==============================================</Box>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="Foo">
    <Message Text="$(Box.Replace(Text, CLEAN UP 1))" Importance="High" />
    <Warning Text="$(Box.Replace(Text, CLEAN UP 2))" />
    <Error Text="$(Box.Replace(Text, CLEAN UP 3))" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Comment: Thank you. But how can i call it and pass a parameter ("CLEAN UP")? As i understand it, `CallTarget` cannot be used to pass parameters. Also properties and item definitions are only visible to other targets once a target finishes.

Comment: Oh ok i now realised that i could define the `Box` property outside of the `Foo` target - "globally" so to speak. then i can use `"$(Box.Replace(Text, CLEAN UP 3))"` anywhere i like to.

Comment: @BatteryBackupUnit Yes, you can define or redefine it anywhere. Personally, I have a custom task and resource file with headers ran through [taag](http://patorjk.com/software/taag), or sometimes even embedded cygwin version of [FIGlet](http://www.figlet.org/).